# Accessing Schema.Types.ObjectId's values with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I'm learning MongoDB and how to use Mongoose,

I'm trying to build a simple Workout manager app, where workouts have a name (Eg: "Upper Body"), an email account (which is used to identify who created the workout) and array of exercise consisting of references to exercises.

I want to be able to have a query where I can access the exercise title(Eg: "Push Ups") by using just the workout name.

My workout.js Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; 
var Exercise = require('./exercise');

const workoutSchema = new Schema({
  title:     {type: 'String', required: true},
  email:      {type: 'String', required: true},
  exercises: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercise' }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Workout', workoutSchema);
```

My exercise.js Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var exerciseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title:       {type: String, required: true}
}, {
   timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Exercise', exerciseSchema);
```

My Workout Controller looks like this :

```
var Workout = require('../models/workout');
var Exercises = require('../models/exercise');

    exports.getWorkoutExercises = function(req, res) {

        Workout.findOne({ title: req.params.workout_name})
          .populate('exercises')
          .exec((err, exercises) => {
            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }

        /* I want to be able to return or access the exercises title */ 
        res.json({exercises.title});
        });

    }
```

In My routes.js i have this :

```
workoutRoutes.get('/:workout_name', WorkoutController.getWorkoutExercises);
```

Any Help or tips is much appreciated !

Comment: Can you show us the exact json output you are expecting for an example workout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you did here res.json({exercises.title}); Can you try this? Hope it works

```
Workout.findOne({ title: req.params.workout_name})
      .populate('exercises')
      .exec((err, workout) => {
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send({ exercises: workout.exercises });
        }
});
```

And then, on your client side, you can iterate the exercises array and access to the title of exercise

Comment: Thanks that helped.!